# What is this type of multiple attribute filtering called? (see screenshot)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, user-interface

aws console uses this great filtering mechanism that lets users filter on multiple attributes. Does anyone know what this is called?

And if so, any implementations in Angular?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUYAg.jpg[image]

Comment: I think you can do something like this using [https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: Thanks your suggestion help. Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yes, I answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very good experience with a framework called  [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to do this.